# is this safe in terms of SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Currently getting more and more into MySQL. It's something i haven't been too fussed about but i want to write some scripts with it now.

My question is simple, im making a search script and just want to know if my php code can prevent some SQL injections.. the code:

```
$orig = $_POST['term'];
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($orig);
$sql = mysql_query("select * from db1 where content like '%$term%' ");
```

Is this ok? Alternatively if anyone has an easier/better/safer way of doing this plese feel inclined to let me know.

Comment: Please take the time to look into using [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or, at the very least, start using [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/mysqli). You will do the world a great service :)

Comment: thanks for the links! ive come quite far in the past week through simple tutorials so i'll give those a look in

Comment: It's probably safe. Of course, `mysql_escape_string()` was also "probably safe" until it was discovered that it wasn't.

Comment: aaah!! you ruined my fairytale ending. so when did that happen?

Comment: Oh the possibilities: [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_escape_string)`This function is identical to mysql_real_escape_string() except that mysql_real_escape_string() takes a connection handler and escapes the string according to the current character set. mysql_escape_string() does not take a connection argument and does not respect the current charset setting.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid warnings in case `$_POST['term']` isn't set:

```
if (isset($_POST['term'])) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from db1 where content like '%$term%' ");
    // rest of sql query
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe from SQL injection. If you want to use a more systematic method of avoiding SQL injection issues I would recommend learning to use PDO and parameterised queries.

Comment: Completely safe?  Hex anyone?

Comment: SELECT LOAD_FILE(0x633A5C626F6F742E696E69) (M)
    This will show the content of c:\boot.ini

Comment: I don't see how you would get that query to execute using the posted code. Please elaborate as to how your example query is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

yes it should be fine with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: thanks! so the way ive set about this is the best practise or is there a better one?

Comment: That is the best practice! (or you use prepared statements)

Comment: It's definitely not "best practice". I strongly advise using an abstract database model, or at least a library like `MySQLi` (as mentioned and linked in Kevin Peno's comment) to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The standard escaping is often insufficient for values used in the `LIKE` clause. Unless you want the user to specify `%` placeholders of his own, you should add:

```
 $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);
 $term = addcslashes($term, "%_");
```

To be precise, this only an issue for very large tables, where excessive `%%%%` placeholder injection in LIKE queries could decelerate the database server.

Answer (score 0):

In your case mysql_real_escape_string will prevent SQL injection because it escapse single quotes and your string is set between single quotes. So in any case $term will always be just a simple string for SQL.

If you have something like

```
select * from A where id = $number
```

then no escaping would prevent an injection like:

```
0; drop A;
```

To prevent this scenario you would go well with prepared statements (PDO) or type-checking.